vba for loop not counting rows correctly
This has me really confused...how come the counter variable "cntr" starts out with a value of 11, but the first time in the loop it gets a value of "102"?
It should be "11" and I don't understand what's going on.
Here's a screenshot of the code next to the debug.print window .

Here's the code:
Public Sub show_NNN_expenses()
    Dim StartRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer, isCamRow As Integer, ii As Integer, cntr As Integer
    
    StartRow = 11
    LastRow = 200
    ii = 0
    cntr = 11
Debug.Print ("Starting")
    'Loop through the rows
    For ii = StartRow To LastRow
Debug.Print ("StartRow " & StartRow & " Last Row: " & LastRow & " Current Row " & ii & " Cntr: " & cntr)
        'hide rows not "NNN" or "CAM"
        isCamRow = InStr(1, Cells(cntr, 1).Value, "CAM")
Debug.Print ("isCamRow " & isCamRow)

        If isCamRow > 0 Then
            'show row
           ' Cells(ii, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            'hide row
           ' Cells(ii, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            
        End If
        
        cntr = cntr + 1
    Next ii
        
End Sub

enter code here

The Immediate window only shows the last 200 lines of output, so the initial values got cut off by the later lines.

Ah, ok, I didn't realize that...I assumed by scrolling to the top, it was actually the top. 2 days on that...frustrating. thanks Tim!
